# Migrate from legacy UUID to standard UUID

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a simple migration framework for mongo that is executing some scripts passed in it.

Now I want to migrate my LUUID to UUID. I wrote following:

```
function fixIds(collectionName) {
    function uuidv4() {
        return 'xxxxxxxxxxxx4xxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    }

    var collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
    var items = collection.find({}).toArray().map(x => Object.assign(x, { _id: UUID(uuidv4()) })); // replace legace UUID with standard UUID
    collection.drop();
    collection.insertMany(items);
}

fixIds("specialoffers");
```

Then I run it:

```
public static async Task<BsonValue> EvalAsync(this IMongoDatabase database, string javascript)
{
    var client = database.Client as MongoClient;

    if (client == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Client is not a MongoClient");

    var function = new BsonJavaScript(javascript);
    var op = new EvalOperation(database.DatabaseNamespace, function, null);

    using (var writeBinding = new WritableServerBinding(client.Cluster, new CoreSessionHandle(new NoCoreSession())))
    {
        return await op.ExecuteAsync(writeBinding, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

It executes, but it replaces LUUID values to other LUUID values. However, when I run very this script in my `Robo 3T` shell it works as expected.

What is wrong with this code? Why it work from the shell only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy worked for me:

```
function fixIds(collectionName) {
    var collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
    var items = collection.find({}).toArray().map(x => Object.assign(x, { _id: new BinData(4, x._id.base64()) })); // replace legacy UUID with standard UUID
    collection.drop();
    collection.insertMany(items);
}

fixIds("specialoffers");
```

I replaced `UUID(uuidv4())` with `new BinData(4, x._id.base64()) })` and this is the only way to correcly update UUID version.

Comment: I'm in this same situation, so I appreciate you posting your solution. I'll try it out tomorrow :)

Comment: @Tomas glad to hear it. I wasted tons of time before I figured out what's wrong so I hope it saves you some too :)